# Get the Form elements from a pdf file

Tags: c#, itext

I want to parse a PDF file , having check box,Radio buttons,Drop downs and text boxes .And I want to parse the PDF file to get each of these control's position and the values.
I am using C# and itextsharp

any suggestions/ideas will be helpful.

What I did so far REF: http://simpledotnetsolutions.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/itextsharp-few-c-examples/

```
   public void ReadPDFformDataPageWise(string inputFile)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFile);
        AcroFields form = reader.AcroFields;
        try
        {
            for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                foreach (string key in form.Fields.Keys)
                {
                    switch (form.GetFieldType(key))
                    {
                        case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_CHECKBOX:
                            //Create Checkbox
                        case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_COMBO:
                        //Create Combo Box
                        case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_LIST:
                        //Create List
                        case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_RADIOBUTTON:
                        //Create Radio button
                        case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_NONE:
                        case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_PUSHBUTTON:
                        //Create Submit Button
                        case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_SIGNATURE:
                        //Create Signature
                        case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_TEXT:
                            //Create textbox/Qs header
                            int fileType = form.GetFieldType(key);
                            string fieldValue = form.GetField(key);
                            float[] a = form.GetFieldPositions(key);
                            string translatedFileName = form.GetTranslatedFieldName(key);
                           AcroFields.Item test=  form.GetFieldItem(key);

                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you referring to unofficial examples, rather than to the official web site?

See http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=121 to find out how to list all fields in an AcroForm, getting their name and type. If you have Checkboxes or Radio fields, you need to get the appearance state as shown in the same example.

If you want to know the page number and position of each field, you need this example: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=163

Look for the method that gets a `FieldPosition` instance.

If you want to know more about the flags that are set for the field (password field, multiline,...) take a look at this example: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=237

If you say: *Mr. Lowagie, I will vote down your answer because you're giving me examples in Java and I only accept C# answers!* Please go to: http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/HEAD/tree/book/

We've invested in porting all the book example to C#. All you have to do, is to walk down the directory tree to find the corresponding examples. For instance: http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/HEAD/tree/book/src/part2/chapter06/FormInformation.java

If you say: none of your examples work, then maybe your form is an XFA form instead of an AcroForm. In that case, there is no such thing as "the position of the field"; with XFA, the PDF file acts as a container of an XML template and data set. This XML is rendered on the fly and the position of each field depends on the dataset. If your question is about XFA, please reconsider.

Note that this answer costs me money, as I'm sharing knowledge you should have obtained from reading [the book I wrote](http://itextpdf.com/book), instead of asking a question that reveals you didn't do much effort to look for a solution yourself ;-)

I didn't downvote the question, but I understand why somebody else would do so.